# Retries not working with fault injection in Istio

Tags: microservices, istio

When I am adding this VirtualService the fault injection is working and I am getting 502 errors. However after I have introduced the retries the error rate is not reduced in the system I am still receiving 50% of errors.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api-broker-timeout
  namespace: four
spec:
  hosts:
  - api-broker-svc
  http:
  - retries:
      attempts: 10
      perTryTimeout: 50mss
      retryOn: gateway-error,5xx,retriable-4xx
    fault:
      delay:
        percent: 100
        fixedDelay: 0.4s
      abort:
        httpStatus: 502
        percent: 50
    route:
    - destination:
        host: api-broker-svc
```

Answer (score 1):

As per VirtualService spec documentation, fault injection and retries do not work together.

Ref: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRoute

> Fault injection policy to apply on HTTP traffic at the client side. Note that timeouts or retries will not be enabled when faults are enabled on the client side.

Edit:

This is being tracked as a future enhancement under https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13705